# How do I display a url link when using a javascript to cloak the full referal link?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm cloaking a referal link so I'm using an onClick function to open a new tab navigating to the linked website.
However, I still want to display the url when the user hovers over the hyperlink text.

So if the referal link is: `www.somelink.com/long_ref_code` then I would like to display only `www.somelink.com` when the user hovers over the a element.

How do I achieve this?

Code:

```
function navigate(newtab){
  var a = document.createElement('a');
     a.href = "http://www.somesite.com/some_long_referal_code";
     if (newTab) {
        a.setAttribute('target', '_blank');
     }
  a.click();
}
```

And the element is:

```
<a onClick="navigate();">Some hyperlink text</a>
```

Comment: can you explain what you want to achieve? this isn't very clear

Comment: @SaadRehman The user should see a link when hovering above the hyperlink text

Comment: and what are you seeing now?

Comment: I have but you should be explaining what your code does and what u want to achieve? Please read the guide on how to ask question.

Comment: Display the url how? The browser native display or custom?

Comment: @morganney if the referal link is: www.somelink.com/long_ref_code then I would like to display only www.somelink.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `preventDefault` to change the default action.

For example, here is an a element that opens it on the same tab (compatible with StackOverflow snippets). As you see, the URL when hovering says https://google.com, but the actual link it sends you to is https://mozilla.org

```js
document.querySelector("a").addEventListener("click", event => {
  event.preventDefault();
  window.location.assign("http://www.mozilla.org");
})
```

```html
<a href="https://google.com">Google</a>
```